# Magento Product Page

Tags: magento, styles

Where exactly can I modify the style for things like buttons on the product page?

The specific problem I am having is that the add-to-cart button is inheriting black font, so that it’s illegible with the black background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every style modification you can refer the style.css of your skin/frontend/package/theme folder.
Use firebug plugin with firefox to check the line number and required styling for any perticular object.

About your add-to-cart button : you can give color background the span element inside the button tag.

Hope that helps.